# Directory indexes are not allowed here. How to fix this?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-urls, django-staticfiles

I am using VueJS for fronend and Django for backend. I changed the conf of Vuejs such that when we run `npm run build` the compiled files goes to static/dist directory of Django. I also added the urls in urls.py as shown

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/',include('users.urls')), 
    path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` index .js is returned which contains the VueJS index file. So the above url goes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/dist` and the server runs normally. But when I reload the page I am getting the below error.

```
Page not found (404)
Directory indexes are not allowed here.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/
Raised by:  django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve
```

Any idea on how to resolve this error?

**settings.py**:

```
"""
Django settings for e_cell_server project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-xbdu73yg0k)p%5$yx2%xa$bqsske-x&e!pljzdgvgeffr+dh+0'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS=[]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #3rd-party
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    # Own Apps
    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'e_cell_server.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'e_cell_server.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')
]
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```